# Cycle Slideshow Plugin Interference with ToggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, cycle, toggleclass

I am using Malsup's Cycle plugin for simple slideshows on a website. (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) Additionally, i have a hidden menu which appears on small devices and uses a toggleClass to show/hide the menu.

It seems as the two are interfering when used in conjunction - I can get the menu to slide into view when triggered, but the slideshow won't work. Or, I can get the slideshow to work, but the menu will not slide in.

Stranger than anything: When I view through Dreamweaver's Preview tool, it works fine, but on a live site the issue persists.

Can anyone offer any insight? Perhaps I have missed something that someone else can catch?

Live site and all code can be viewed here: http://rai.desensdesigns.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your slideshow and menu are both working. checked in ios and ff

Comment: I have updated the cycle plugin - the updated version was loaded 18 days ago on GitHub. 

The site is working again. Thanks!